# goroutine create multiple mongodb connection

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

How to manage MongoDB connection for more than 100000 goroutines in golang.

I have created one `*mongo.Client` instance then using this same client but it creates multiple connections.

Comment: `mongo.Client` manages an internal connection pool. You do not have to worry about that. `mongo.Client` is safe for concurrent use. What is your problem or question?

Comment: @icza but it shows more than 10000 connection and getting too slow operations can you suggest any solution, Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`mongo.Client`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Client) manages an internal connection pool. You do not have to worry about that. `mongo.Client` is safe for concurrent use.

If you want to limit the internal pool, you may do so at connection using [`ClientOptions`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.5.3/mongo/options#ClientOptions). For example:

```
clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI("<your-connection-string>").
    SetMaxPoolSize(100) // Allow no more than 100 connections

client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOpts)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Quoting from [`ClientOptions.SetMaxPoolSize()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.5.3/mongo/options#ClientOptions.SetMaxPoolSize):

> SetMaxPoolSize specifies that maximum number of connections allowed in the driver's connection pool to each server. Requests to a server will block if this maximum is reached. This can also be set through the "maxPoolSize" URI option (e.g. "maxPoolSize=100"). The default is 100. If this is 0, it will be set to math.MaxInt64.

`ClientOptions` also has methods for setting the `MaxConnIdleTime` and `MinPoolSize` properties.

But know that this won't speed things up. If you have a hundred thousand goroutines all interacting with MongoDB, likely MongoDB will be your bottleneck.