# Is mongodb client driver concurrent safe?

Tags: database, mongodb, go, goroutine, mongo-go

In the below code from [codebase](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver), mongodb client is created(as shown below):

```
import (
    "context"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)

ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
```

---

In our scenario:

Goroutine 1 uses `collection1` for read & write operations:

```
  collection1 := client.Database("testing").Collection("collectionone")
```

Go-routine 2 uses both `collection1` &`collection2` for read & write operations:

```
 collection2 := client.Database("testing").Collection("collectiontwo")
```

---

Is `client` concurrent safe to be used in multiple go-routines?

Comment: Concurrency safety is a problem the database itself has to deal with. What if your code connects and someone else from another application as well? So you really have to ask yourself, is mongodb concurrency safe?

Comment: @TheFool mongodb is concurrent safe. But my question is, is client driver concurrent safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation of [`mongo.Database`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database) explicitly states that:

> Database is a handle to a MongoDB database. **It is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.**

And [`mongo.Client`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Client) that:

> Client is a handle representing a pool of connections to a MongoDB deployment. **It is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.**

And [`mongo.Collection`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection):

> Collection is a handle to a MongoDB collection. **It is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.**

See related: [goroutine create multiple mongodb connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862292/goroutine-create-multiple-mongodb-connection/67862482#67862482)

Answer (score 1):

As per mongoDB documentation - A cursor is not goroutine safe. Do not use the same cursor in multiple goroutines at the same time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).